# Omit leading in ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to reuse ListTile. If leading parameter isn't specified I want to skip the leading being drawn. I have tried common practice by replacing it with empty container but that doesn't work. The container must have some size otherwise it crash. But even if you give the container 1px size then it will create big space on the left of tile

[image]

```
class SimpleListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Widget leading;

  const SimpleListTile({@required this.title, this.leading});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
        leading: leading == null ? Container() : leading, title: Text(title));
  }
}
```

Is there any way to skip leading being drawn without creating 2 tiles in if statement because I want to do the same thing with trailing widget

Comment: Does simple omitting the `leading` parameter work for you?

Comment: Or either explicitly providing `null` instead of an empty `Container`?

Comment: @AndreyOzornin Damn... yes.. replacing container with null works.. I don't know why I din't try it... Thanks. Fell free to answer it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either omitting of the `leading` property or explicitly providing `null` instead of an empty container seems to do it:

```dart
return ListTile(
  title: Text(title);
);
```

or

```dart
return ListTile(
  title: Text(title);
  leading: leading // regardless of is it null or not
);
```